# Querydsl error on deploy heroku

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, spring-boot, querydsl

I have a Springboot application using gradle that builds fine on my local machine, but when i try to deploy it on heroku i get the following output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * Where:
   Build file '/tmp/build_67ca1dce3ca8263f014681c911e8b92e/build.gradle' line: 24

   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'build_67ca1dce3ca8263f014681c911e8b92e'.
   > Could not generate a proxy class for class  com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.tasks.QuerydslCompile.
```

Does anyone have any ideia on what the problem is?

Below is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.4"
        classpath("org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.1")
        classpath "info.robotbrain.gradle.lombok:lombok-gradle:1.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl"
apply plugin: 'flyway'
apply plugin: "info.robotbrain.lombok"

// Profile
def env = hasProperty('profile') ? profile : 'dev'
apply from: "${env}.gradle"

// QueryDSL
querydsl {
    jpa = true
}

jar {
    baseName = 'web-server'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //Spring Boot
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    }

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    // QueryDSL
    compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.6.1")

    // PostGreSQL
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1202-jdbc42")

    // Guava
    compile("com.google.guava:guava:18.0")

    //Quartz-Scheduler
    compile("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1")

    //Spring
    compile('org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.1.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.1.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.2.1.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.1.RELEASE')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'

    //Mail
    compile('javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.4')
    compile('com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.4')

    //Lombok
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok-maven:1.16.6.1')

    //Security
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.8.RELEASE')


    compile('javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0-m01')

    //Guice
    compile('com.google.inject:guice:3.0')

    //Jersey
    compile('com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.18')

    //Dozer
    compile('net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.5.1')

    //Flyway API
    compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:3.2.1"

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:1.2.1")
    testCompile("org.dbunit:dbunit:2.5.0")
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.0.0')
    testCompile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.1')
    testCompile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.6.1")

    configurations.all {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'net.xendurance.webServer.configuration.WebServerApplication'
}

task stage {
    dependsOn installDist
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run `./gradlew clean stage` locally?

Comment: Please also share the `build.gradle` file, it might be very helpful.

Comment: I will run the command and share the build file like @Opal said later today, when i get home.

Comment: @codefinger, i ran the command locally, and the build was sucessfull.

Comment: @Opal, added the build.gradle file

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using locally? What version on Heroku?

Comment: Also what are the contents of `dev.gradle`? Does Heroku run with a different env for that file?

Comment: JDK 8 on both environments.
dev.gradle has only DB configurations for the flyway migrate proccess, i don't think it has anything to do with that, do you?